# Read csv with duplicate column headers in Python

Tags: python, csv, header

I want to read a csv as a dictionary in Python, but now I encountered a problem, because the csv contains headers used more than once, like this:

| id | name | labels | labels |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | one | mytask | myproduct |
| 02 | two | mylabel |  |

The standard way to import a csv to python looks like this:

```py
# import csv
import csv
# read csv file to a list of dictionaries
with open('data.csv', 'r') as file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    data = [row for row in csv_reader]
print(data)
```

Sadly this code swallows up the first 'labels' value if there is more than one. This code outputs this:

```py
[
    {'id': '01', 'name': 'one', 'labels': 'myproduct'},
    {'id': '02', 'name': 'two', 'labels': 'mylabel'},
]
```

Is there any way to read also the second value for 'labels' without getting to complicated? My preferred output would look like this:

```py
[
    {'id': '01', 'name': 'one', 'labels': ['mytask', 'myproduct']},
    {'id': '02', 'name': 'two', 'labels': 'mylabel'},
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define your own reader which correctly handles files where duplicate headers exist.

When you initialize the reader, parse the first row to map all header names to the corresponding column indices. When you read the rows, iterate through this map, and assign the values to the correct keys of an output dictionary based on the header name-to-column index map you created earlier.

```
import csv

class DHDictReader():
    def __init__(self, iterable, dialect='excel', **kwargs):
        self._reader = csv.reader(iterable, dialect, **kwargs)
        
        # Get header row
        headers = next(self._reader)

        # Map header names to column indices
        self._row_cols = {}
        for i, h in enumerate(headers):
            if h in self._row_cols:
                self._row_cols[h].append(i)
            else:
                self._row_cols[h] = [i]
    
    # The iterator for this object is itself -- 
    # calling __next__ on this object yields the next record
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        # Get next row
        row = next(self._reader)
        out_row = {}
        for header, col_indices in self._row_cols.items():
            # Create list containing all non-empty values for this header
            out_row[header] = [row[i] for i in col_indices if i < len(row) and row[i]]

            # If this header contains only one value, change it from a list to the first element of the list
            if len(out_row[header]) == 1:
                out_row[header] = out_row[header][0]

        return out_row
    
    @property
    def dialect(self):
        return self._reader.dialect
    
    @property
    def line_num(self):
        return self._reader.line_num
    
    @property
    def fieldnames(self):
        return self._row_cols.keys()
```

The properties are just to expose attributes that [other reader objects from the `csv` module also have](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#reader-objects)

Now, this class should be a drop-in replacement for a regular `DictReader`:

```
file_contents = """id,name,labels,labels
01,one,mytask,myproduct
02,two,mylabel
"""

with open('my_file.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(file_contents)

with open('my_file.csv') as f:
    reader = DHDictReader(f)
    print(list(reader))
```

will list out the records in the way you want:

```
[
  {'id': '01', 'name': 'one', 'labels': ['mytask', 'myproduct']}, 
  {'id': '02', 'name': 'two', 'labels': 'mylabel'}
]
```

Comment: I like that solution the most because it does not alter my existing function to much. I can just add a comment for the next developer the original function is overloaded because of the duplicate label issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can skip header and manipulate data manually after loading csv

```
import csv
raw ="""id,name,label,label\n1,aaa,a1,a2\n2,bbb,b1,b2\n3,ccc,c1,c2""".splitlines()[1:]
parsed = list(csv.reader(a))
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd do it like this:

```
dictionary = {}

for row in range(2, lastRow):
   for col in range(1, lastCol):

      headline_cell = worksheet.Cells(1, col).Value
      cell = worksheet.Cells(row, col).Value

      if headline_cell in dictionary:

        if isinstance(dictionary[headline_cell], list) == False:
          dictionary[headline_cell] = [dictionary[headline_cell]]
        else:
          dictionary[headline_cell].append(cell)

      else:
        dictionary[headline_cell] = cell
```

You have to get the last used column and row for the whole csv first though.